# Chebyshev Type 1 Low-pass filter in matlab

Tags: matlab, filter, signal-processing

I am trying to use [designfilt](https://de.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/designfilt.html) from matlab in order to design a Type 1 Chebyshev low-pass filter, however, I keep getting errors such as:

> Error using designfilt (line 411)
>
> Filter response is not valid.

My code is relatively simple:

```
filt = designfilt('cheby1','FilterOrder',3,'CutoffFrequency', 20, 'PassbandRipple', 10);

filtered_signal = filter(filt, signal);
```

What this should have done is, create a Chebyshev Type 1 filter, with order 3, cutoff frequency of 20 Hz and a Passband Ripple of 10 Hz. Last, but not least, it should have called it on my signal, with the name signal.

Is there something more to implementing a low-pass Chebyshev Type 1 filter in matlab, or have I simply mixed up the in the inputs of `designfilt`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your issue here, there a few of them:

1. `'cheby1'` is not one of the allowed strings for `designfilt`'s first argument (MATLAB 2014).  If you type `help designfilt` it will give you a list of the different options that are allowed. The closest I see is: `'lowpassiir'`.
   Checkout example 3 in particular for using the parameter `'designmethod'` with a named filter (e.g. `'cheby1'`).
2. The `'PassbandRipple`' is not specified in Hz, but in dB.  It's not a frequency range, but a specification of the desired magnitude response of your ripple in the specified frequency range.
3. Use `'PassbandFrequency'` instead of `'CutoffFrequency'` in this case.  The Chebyshev filter has a passband with a specified, maximum ripple allowed, across that band of frequency.  In a low pass filter, conceptually it is cutoff at the end of the frequency, but here it understood to pass frequency from 0 to what you are specifying as the cutoff frequency.
4. You are specifying your frequency units in Hz (i.e. not normalized 0 to 1), but have not given specified your sampling frequency.  You can specify your frequency as normalized units and not include a sampling frequency, otherwise it needs to be included

Here is what it will look like with a sample rate of 100 Hz.

```
filt = designfilt('lowpassiir', 'FilterOrder', 3, 'PassbandFrequency', 20,...
                  'PassbandRipple', 10, 'SampleRate', 100, 'DesignMethod', 'cheby1');
```

You may be better off using `cheby1` (the method) directly for designing your filter coefficients, and then pass that to `filter`.  Here's the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/cheby1.html).  This way there are not as many options to mix and match which and the references may help hone in on any discrepancies earlier.

Comment: Under `'DesignMethod'` there is the option to use `cheby1`, so I that is why I tried using it.

Comment: Okay, but you have to pass it in is as named value pair, not as the first argument.  See example 2 of `help designfilt`.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: No sweat.  I appreciated your follow-on comment regarding `'DesignMethod'`; I learned more about `designfilt` because of it.